# Can I add a new class to the pre-trained YOLO model by using a custom dataset?

Tags: dataset, tensorflow-datasets, yolov5, yolov8

I want to add the object trained with the custom dataset to the other 80 object YOLO weights, As a single weight of 80+1. Meaning, increase the weight of the existing 80 objects.

Because, normally, YOLO weight consists of 80 objects.